# Counting primes in residue classes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Suppose you are sorting all of the prime numbers between $1$ and some large number $N$, from smallest to largest; into buckets which correspond to their residue classes modulo some prime $p_i$.

Now suppose you actually had two copies of the prime numbers between $1$ and some large number $N$; one to be sorted by residue classes modulo prime $p_i$, and the other to be sorted by residue classes modulo prime $p_{i+1}$.

At each step in time you place the smallest prime number and its copy into the two buckets as instructed above.

At what point in time can you be sure that, all of the buckets that correspond to residue classes of $p_i$ (excluding bucket $[0]_i$) contain more prime numbers than any of the buckets corresponding to residue classes of $p_{i+1}$.

Or can you never be sure?

Comment: By Bertrands postulate, and random distribution ( not really, as some residues depend on multiplier), you get each residue class  mod the later primes is over half the amount in any residue mod the former.

Comment: It depends how elementary you want it to be. For a fixed pair $q_1,q_2$ the prime number theorem in arithmetic progressions is effective, you can compute (from the values of Dirichlet L-functions $\bmod q_i$ near $s=1$) a constant $C$ such that $\forall x$, for $q_i \nmid a$, $$|\sum_{p \le x, p \equiv a \bmod q_i} 1-\frac{x}{(p-1)\log x}| < C\frac{x}{\log^2 x}$$ I don't think there is a simple [formula](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/the-prime-number-theorem-in-arithmetic-progressions-and-dueling-conspiracies/) for $C(q)$ which would work for all $q$

Comment: Don't all the primes go into the residue classes modulo $p_i$ and $p_{i+1}$. Why would more primes be in one and not the other? Can you clarify?